# Não consigo acessar o tfs pelo visual 2017(Português)

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server

Estou tentando acessar o TFS pelo VS2017 e não estou conseguindo. O erro diz assim:

> O servidor 'http://xx.xxx.x.xx:porta/tfs' não foi adicionado.TF30063.
>   Você não está autorizado acessar: 'http://xx.xxx.x.xx:porta/tfs'

Bem, eu tenho minha conta com o email da **hotmail** e o meu líder me adicionou nos projetos da empresa. Abaixo screenshot da tela do VS2017 com TFS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu insiro a url do servidor e recebo o erro acima citado. O que mais devo fazer? Preciso de alguma configuração extra? Fico no aguardo.

Comment: Quem é o administrador do servidor TFS? Não é só lhe adicionar, provavelmente ele vai ter que adicionar o seu usuário as permissões para ler e escrever no projeto

Comment: @JoeTorres, imaginei algo parecido, mas como ele não chegou, estou à espera, mas me falaram que tem um cara aqui que resolve e estou aguardando ele terminar de falar com o líder dele e depois vou ver o que tá acontecendo.

Comment: Saquei. As vezes tem que ver se ele deu a permissão para algum grupo do AD tb, e vc tem que estar nele para acessar. Mas quem vai saber mesmo é o adm.

Comment: @JoeTorres, acho que o problema está no meu usuário. Quando instalei o VS eu fiz com um usuário do Hotmail. Esse usuário não tem as permissões. Preciso logar com outro usuário e não sei como fazer. Não consigo um **run as different user** no VS2017. Isso é que eu preciso fazer.

Comment: Digito um user diferente e está dano usuário ou senha errados

Comment: Nesse caso não precisa se preucupar com isso. Se souber uma conta que funcione nesse repositorio e quiser testar ela, abre essa janera de conectar-se a um servidor, e adicione uma conta nova, clicando naquela setinha do lado do seu email e escolhendo adicionar uma nova conta. Aqui tem onde clicar: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ag-CqQT8l3usjsg4Vf_SDAeZyZLG_g

Comment: @JoeTorres, isso não tem funcionado. Já tentei e nada. Não aceita outra conta. A MS pede uma conta nesse formato: **nome@dominio.extensão** e eu tenho isso: **nome.nome** apenas e não consigo. O **link** acima que vc passou, não abre aqui na empresa. O firewall barra.

Comment: O repositório que vc está tentando conectar é numa rede interna ou está nesses repositórios de contas do visual studio?

Comment: Amigo, se você está tentando se conectar a um Tfs on-premisses (que pelo modelo de url que vc colocou é oque está tentando), você não vai autenticar com o @hotmail, mas sim com seu usuário de rede, tipo contoso\usuario

Comment: @JoeTorres eJulio, bom dia. Consegui. Era só deslogar do Visual Studio. Fiz isso e consegui acessar o tfs. Valeu a todos e obrigado.

Comment: Fantástico. Microsoft e suas soluções fantáasticas rsr.

Comment: @JoeTorres, no comments. kkkk. Muito bom.